# Creating a Taxonomy Page

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, archives, template-hierarchy

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the way to set up a taxonomy template page.

My goal is to create a taxonomy archive of a custom taxonomy I created. The page would only need to contain a list of all the terms in the taxonomy.

My main problem is not creating the list but more so naming the file correctly. Wouldn't the file be called taxonomy.php. How would I be able to view this page once I created it.

Answer (score 0):

you can name the file in this way: `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` as described in this [page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), there you can create a loop adn WP will only select the elements of the given taxonomy.